# Create/append nested dictionary inside a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to append a dictionary?
I tried `maindict[a] = m` and `maindict[a][x] = n`. It didnt work, I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

```
maindict = 
{ 'a' : '',
  'b' : '',
...
}

m = 
{ 'x' : '', 
  'y' : ''}

n = 
{ 'l' : '', 
  'm' : ''}
```

tobe

```
maindict =  { 'a' : { 'x' : { 'l' : '', 
  'm' : ''}, 'y' : ''},   
'b' : '', ... }
```

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.   
Your partial code indicates that `maindict` is a dictionary, but the error message implies a list.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to recognize that your dictionary keys are string literals, not variables.

```
maindict['a'] = m
maindict['a']['x'] = n
```